# Pass argument to function

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I have an svg element that user can click or double-click.
I want to dispatch both events, so I use this method:

```
svg.attr('class', 'country')
    .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
    .attr('d', path)
    .on('click', checkIfClickOrDoubleClick);

function checkIfClickOrDoubleClick(d, i) {
    if(dblclick_timer) {
        clearTimeout(dblclick_timer);
        dblclick_timer = false;
        console.log('double click on i =', i, '/ d =', d);
    } 
    else { 
        dblclick_timer = setTimeout(function() {
            dblclick_timer = false;
            console.log('single click on i=', i, '/ d =', d);
            // CREATE OTHER PATH ELEMENT
        }, 250)
    } 
}
```

The problem is that when user click on the SVG, the code creates other path element that user can click or double-click.
So I have something like:

```
function checkIfClickOrDoubleClick(d, i) {
    if(dblclick_timer) {
        clearTimeout(dblclick_timer);
        dblclick_timer = false;
        console.log('double click on i =', i, '/ d =', d);
    } 
    else { 
        dblclick_timer = setTimeout(function() {
            dblclick_timer = false;
            console.log('single click on i=', i, '/ d =', d);
            // CREATE OTHER PATH ELEMENT
            svg.selectAll(null)
                .data(features)
                .enter().append('path')
                .attr('fill', function(r, i) { 
                    return 'tomato'; // r are the regions, i are the indices of regions
                })
                .attr('d', path)
                .on('click', checkIfClickOrDoubleClick);
        }, 250)
    } 
}
```

As you can see, I have to check if use clicked or double-clicked. So in total I have 4 different interactions.
Is there a way to pass a parameter to `checkIfClickOrDoubleClick()` so I can distinguish in which case I am?
Otherwise I think to create another method `checkIfClickOrDoubleClick2`, but I don't think is the best solution.

Comment: *"Otherwise I think to create another method, but I don't think is the best solution"*. Why? I've seen people bending over backwards to do microoptimisations or reducing the code as if it was a code golf... My suggestion is: just create the second function. My first computer had 2KiB of RAM (that`s right, 2048 bytes), but now computers are insanely fast and have a lot of memory/storage. Of course, I'm not advocating for lazy or slow code, I'm just saying that creating a second function is an easy solution, that uses few resources and that can make your code even more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one event handler with switch statement inside. To see what is fired, check **event.type** within the handler (in your case event is d3.event). To get the element either use **this** or **event.currentTarget**.

If you detected dblclick and don't want to call click case, add a property on the element itself like this._dblclicked or event.currentTarget._dblclicked and then in the click case if you detect the property within a time window, then opt out.